# JPA - working with many-to-many tables with additional information contained in them

Tags: java, database, jpa

**Background Context**

Before going into the issue, I'd first I'd like to note that I only ever need to use JPA to read my schema - no data will be affected/altered in the database by this application, ever.

**Many To Many Join Issue**

I have a many-to-many join table in my schema called `ParamInParamClass` which has additional non-key data contained in it.  In JPA though, we'd usually use a join-table many-to-many syntax to join the `ParamClass` table to `Param` to get a list of `Param` objects in `ParamClass`.

[image: entity relationship diagram]

So, if I use this join syntax:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
        name="ParamInParamClass",
        joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "FKParamClassID", referencedColumnName = "ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name="FKParamID", referencedColumnName="ID")})
private List<Parameter> params;
```

in `ParamClass`, then I cannot access `DefaultOverride  | MinimumOverride | MaximumOverride` in `ParamInParamClass`.

How do I address this situation?

Comment: check http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/

Comment: Thanks, that looks useful. Can the same thing be implemented using JPA on top of hibernate? (I'm looking into it now, just asking in parallel).

Comment: See this manual done by EclipseLink suggesting a JPA way to solve this issue: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany#Mapping_a_Join_Table_with_Additional_Columns

Comment: essentially what they are doing is representing the Many-To-Many relationship as TWO many-to-one (one-to-many) relationships and delegate the setting of the child-parent relation to a third entity class(table), which can have as many extra columns as you like.

Comment: Got it, thank you all for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this based on @perissf's link and also learned some useful information from @hovanessyan's hibernate link.

I'm providing the answer below because, while this uses information from the link, the code straight from the link didn't work for me with JPA/Hibernate - I had to use the extra code noted in the commented section of the links code.  So, reading this on top of the link will hopefully same someone else some time.

---

The solution was to change the `ParameterClass` code that I provided into this:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parameterClass")
private List<ParamInParamClass> parameters;
public List<ParamInParamClass> getParameters() { return parameters; }
```

I then had to create the `ParamInParamClass` entity which was not required before as normally a many-to-many relationship doesn't require you to define the join table.  It needs to be defined here as I'm getting extra fields from it though.

In the `ParamInParamClass` class, I had to explicitly link the entities:

```
@Id
@Column
private String fkParamClassID;
public String getFKParamClassID(){ return fkParamClassID; }
public void setFKParamClassID (String value) { fkParamClassID = value; }

@Id
@Column
private String fkParamID;
public String getFKParamID(){ return fkParamID; }
public void setFKParamID (String value) { fkParamID = value; }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Join columns based on key columns.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fkParamClassID", referencedColumnName = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private ParameterClass parameterClass;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fkParamID", referencedColumnName = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Parameter parameter;
```

and I also had to make sure this ParamInParamClass class used a @IdClass as it has more than one @Id attribute.